# multiple wait.untill inside custom Click

Tags: c#, selenium, xunit

I have created a custom click method that waits until the element is clickable before it click the element. the method works well, but I need to add some more `wait.Until` to make the click method more stable.

This is what i have.

```
public static void WaitAndJsClick(this Browser browser, IWebElement element, int seconds = 30)
{
    var LoadingProgressBar = "(//*[@class='progress-bar'])[2]";
    var loading = "loading";
    var spinner = "spinner";

    var wait = new WebDriverWait(browser.Driver, new TimeSpan(0, 0, seconds));
    wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.InvisibilityOfElementLocated(By.ClassName(loading)));
    wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.InvisibilityOfElementLocated(By.ClassName(spinner)));
    wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.InvisibilityOfElementLocated(By.XPath(LoadingProgressBar)));
    wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(element));

    element.JsClick(browser);   // Click

    wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.InvisibilityOfElementLocated(By.ClassName(loading)));
    wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.InvisibilityOfElementLocated(By.ClassName(spinner)));
    wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.InvisibilityOfElementLocated(By.XPath(LoadingProgressBar)));
    wait.IgnoreExceptionTypes(typeof(NoSuchElementException));
}
```

Now as you can see, I wait for three elements to be "invisible" before it clicks, and after the click it waits for the elements again to be "invisible"

My questions is really, how could I improve this? is this even a good solution? 
it looks like a mess, but working really good.

Comment: Maybe instead of waiting for your loading spinner to be invisible, you could just wait for your element to be clickable ?

Comment: @NicolasG.Duvivier Yes. I have that condition already. The problem is that the element get clickable before the loading spinner disappears so Selenium cant "get" the button :(

Comment: Sorry, I didn't pay enough attention to your code. Does it consider the element to be clickable when the spinner is already there, or is it because the spinners shows up with a bit of lag and then the wait is already executed ?

Comment: @NicolasG.Duvivier yes exactly, that is the problem, and the reason i need to wait for three elements to disappear first.

Comment: Is it a method that you are only using when expecting a spinner ?

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar issue, and this is what i did to ensure stability for such cases.

```
    private const int RetryIntervalInMilliSeconds = 2000;
    private const int AjaxReqTimeoutInMilliSeconds = 20000;

    public void WaitForAjax()
    {
        var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        while (stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds < AjaxReqTimeoutInMilliSeconds)
        {
            try
            {
                Thread.Sleep(RetryIntervalInMilliSeconds);
                var ajaxIsComplete = (bool)browser.ExecuteJavascript("return window.jQuery && jQuery.active == 0");
                if (ajaxIsComplete)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                return;
            }
        }
    }
```

Then i replaced all the calls i have that wait for spinners and progress bars with the call WaitForAjax().

You could technically remove the sleeps and just simply use the javascript ajaxComplete in an expectedCondition to return true.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you, the Ajax loading is actually my biggest problem. 
Will try this now

Comment: No problem. let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a big fan of generic methods that wait for a bunch of stuff. I think it makes things more confusing and harder to debug when things go wrong. I would write a function for each "thing" you need to wait for... progress bar, spinner, loading message, etc. and then call them when you need them.

```
public static void WaitForLoading(this Browser browser)
{
    new WebDriverWait(browser.Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(ExpectedConditions.InvisibilityOfElementLocated(By.ClassName("loading")));
}
public static void WaitForProgressBar(this Browser browser)
{
    new WebDriverWait(browser.Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(ExpectedConditions.InvisibilityOfElementLocated(By.XPath("(//*[@class='progress-bar'])[2]")));
}
public static void WaitForSpinner(this Browser browser)
{
    new WebDriverWait(browser.Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(ExpectedConditions.InvisibilityOfElementLocated(By.ClassName("spinner")));
}
```

Then when you need to wait for the progress bar after clicking an element, you do something like this

```
element.JsClick(browser);
WaitForProgressBar(browser);
```

Now your code to wait for each "thing" only exists in one place (follows [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)) and is easier to maintain.

Comment: totally agree with you!, And this was how I first did it,  unfortunately the people responsible for the framework says it gets to messy to read the test.

Comment: Do you always need to wait for all three? Is that the issue? I would discuss with them what is more important... clarity of what is being done or one-liners. With this method, it is completely clear what you are waiting for each time. If you have a generic method "waitForStuff", it's not clear what you are waiting for. Yes, in the case of three methods you will have three lines of code but you should always favor clarity over an extra two lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

`wait.IgnoreExceptionTypes(typeof(NoSuchElementException));` makes no sense here. If you really want to ignore some exceptions, execute this method right after instantiation of this new Wait object